# Usage of --record in kubectl imperative commands in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I tried to find useful information when should i use `--record`. I created 3 commands:

- `k set image deployment web1 nginx=lfccncf/nginx:latest --record`
- `k rollout undo deployment/web1  --record`
- `k -n kdpd00202 edit deployment web1 --record`

Could anyone tell me if I need to use `--record` in each of these 3 commands?

When is it necessary to use `--record` and when is it useless?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can specify the `--record` flag to write the command executed in the resource annotation `kubernetes.io/change-cause`. The recorded change is useful for future introspection. For example, to see the commands executed in each Deployment revision.

```
kubectl rollout history deployment.v1.apps/nginx-deployment
The output is similar to this:

deployments "nginx-deployment"
REVISION    CHANGE-CAUSE
1           kubectl apply --filename=https://k8s.io/examples/controllers/nginx-deployment.yaml --record=true
2           kubectl set image deployment.v1.apps/nginx-deployment nginx=nginx:1.16.1 --record=true
3           kubectl set image deployment.v1.apps/nginx-deployment nginx=nginx:1.161 --record=true
```

So it's not mandatory for any of the commands and but is recommended for `kubectl set image` because you will not see anything in `CHANGE-CAUSE` section as above if you skip `--record`

Comment: If you want to see the parameters from a recorded declarative command, do `kubectl rollout history deployment.v1.apps/nginx-deployment --revision=[revision_number]`

Answer (score 15):

Kubernetes desired state can be updated/mutated thru two paradigms :

1. Either **imperatively** using kubectl adhoc commands ( `k set`, `k create`, `k run`, `k rollout` ,..)
2. Or **declaratively** using YAML manifests with a single `k apply`

The declarative way is ideal for treating your k8s manifests as Code, then you can share this Code with the team, version it thru Git for example, and keep tracking its history leveraging GitOps practices ( branching models, Code Review, CI/CD ).

However, the imperative way cannot be reviewed by the team as these adhoc-commands will be run by an individual and no one else can easily find out the **cause of the change** after the change has been made.

To overcome the absence of an audit trail with imperative commands, the `--record` option is there to bind the root cause of the change as annotation called `kubernetes.io/change-cause` and the value of this annotation is the imperative command itself.

(note below is from the [official doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/))

> Note: You can specify the --record flag to write the command executed in the resource annotation kubernetes.io/change-cause. The recorded change is useful for future introspection. For example, to see the commands executed in each Deployment revision.

As conclusion :

- Theoretically ,`--record` is not mandatory
- Practically, it's mandatory in order to ensure the changes leave a rudimentary audit trail behind and comply with SRE process and DevOps culture.

Answer (score 0):

`--record` flag also helps to see the details of the revision history, so rollback to a previous version also would be smoother.

When you don't append `--record` flag Change-Cause table will be just `<none>` in
`kubectl rollout history`

```
$ kubectl rollout history deployment/app
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
1         <none>
2         <none>
3         <none>
```